# saml2 idp authentication forwarding

Tags: authentication, keycloak, saml-2.0, shibboleth, simplesamlphp

I have an app that authenticate against an idP using SAML2.
The app support only one idP.
The app is multi-tenant, and I need to forward each tenant user to their own idP.
So I need my local idP (MyIdP, that is registered in the app) to ask the user for their tenat name and based on that, forward the authentication to the appropiate idP and then return it result to the app as its result.
Something like a idP proxy (Is there a name for this functionality???)
Is it possible to do it using SimpleSAMLphp, Shibboleth, Keycloak or any other open source idP?

(App)----->(MyIdP)-----------------------------(idP-Tenant-A)
                       |                                          |-----(idP-Tenant-B)
       { Ask User Tenant Name                    |-----(idP-Tenant-C)
        and forward based on it }

Thanks

Comment: Writing or setting up your own multitenant Relying Identity Provider that understands multitenancy and is safe in terms of possible security issues involving users intentionally switching tenants between redirects is not easy. Without knowing your details it's difficult to go deeper, however, I'd consider making the app multitenant and just going to the idp on specific tenant (and validate the tenant), without the extra idp in the middle.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but unfortunately I can't modify the apps since its not mine, so I need the Relying Identity Provider in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Shibboleth this is called IdP Proxy as you guessed.
[Here is the docs from Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/1459979597/Using+SAML+Proxying+to+another+IdP)

In keycloak, you can do this using their identity brokering functionality. This can act as a proxy between different protocols like OIDC and SAML, but also from SAML to SAML. [Have a look here for their documentation](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/identity-broker.html)

[On my blog I have a post](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/saml-for-react-spa/) showing how to use this as a proxy between OIDC and SAML. But the mechanics are the same if you want to proxy for SAML.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Is it possible to have more than one backend idP, like tenant-A, tenant-B and tenant-C ? In the Shibboleth doc I only see one backend idP set...

Comment: I did some digging and asked around. It should the Shib team says you can configure it, but I couldnt find any good documentation on how to do it.